# How Do I know What To Use For Killin'?

Tags: castaway

So I'm playing [Castaway](http://www.kongregate.com/games/likwidgames/castaway), and I eventually earn some quest items, such as the *Beetle Shield* and the *Fire Scimitar*.  Unfortunately, in this game, there's no way to view the stats of an item, other than in the shop.  How do I know how these items compare with the others in the shop?

Comment: This question has an excellent title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those stats in the shop aren't the items' actual stats. They're the stats relative to your current equipment's stats. So, all you have to do is equip the unique item that you want to compare and visit the Blacksmith to see how much better/worse every item sold is. There is a bug however that the stats in the shop won't know that you have stuff equipped right after loading your game until you enter an area and come back.

If you want to compare two quest-rewarded items, you can equip one, look at your stats and then equip the other one. (That's assuming that there are more than one item per equipment type. I'm only roughly 1/4 done with the game.)

Comment: I figured that much out.   What about, say, the 'magical' stats on the *Fire Schimitar* ?  It's weaker than the second sword in the shop, but it does fire damage every now and then.  Is there a way I can see **these** stats?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but I don't have that yet.

Comment: Okay, I got the Fire Scimitar. It says when you hover over it in your inventory that it has a 10% chance of casting Flame when you use it.